# Permissions deselected, but user can still edit content

Tags: 7, users

Reproduce:

1. Create new content type with uid:1
2. In `admin/people/permissions` you can see that permissions are not given to Administrator role, they are deselected/unticked by default for the new content type.
3. E.g. create new user and give him Administrator permissions.
4. The new Administrator user (non-uid:1) can still edit/create/delete the new content type contents although the permissions are deselected?

[image]

How's that?

Comment: You need disabled option "view, edit, delete any content"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need disabled option "view, edit, delete any content". If this option is checked, next options not used.